# помогите разобраться в коде ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript

опишите, пожалуйста, что происходит в этом коде?

```
package
{
   import flash.display.MovieClip;

   public dynamic class Reload extends MovieClip
   {


      public var textLabel:MovieClip;

      public function Reload()
      {
         super();
         addFrameScript(0,this.frame1);
      }

      function frame1() : *
      {
         stop();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это, судя по всему, декомпилированный код из кадра MovieClip'а, который был добавлен в визуальном редакторе Flash.

MovieClip#addFrameScript - недокументированный метод, который принимает два аргумента. Номер кадра и ссылка на функцию.
Функция будет вызвана по достижению переданного кадра, причём кадры для addFrameScript нумеруются с нуля.

В двух словах - это MovieClip со stop'ом в первом кадре.

Comment: подскажите, а этот стоп можно программно вызвать, в коде javascript, не меняя сам код от flash?

Comment: Не меняя флешового кода - никак. Смотрите справку ExternalInterface.